# Calculate $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int _{0}^{7 x} (1+t^2)^3 dt}{\sin x}$ using L'Hospital Rule

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int _{0}^{7 x} (1+t^2)^3 dt}{\sin x}$

**My try:**

Without L'Hospital Rule I have:
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int _{0}^{7 x} (1+t^2)^3 dt}{\sin x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{7^6x^7+\frac{3}{5}(7x)^5+(7x)^3+7x}{x}=7$$But from L'Hospital Rule I have:
$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int _{0}^{7 x} (1+t^2)^3 dt}{\sin x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{3(1+(7x)^2)^2\cdot14x}{\cos x}=0$$

Where have I got a mistake?

Comment: You made a mistake while taking the derivative of the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac d {dx} \int_0^{7x} (1+t^{2})^{3}dt=7(1+(7x)^{2})^{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying L'hospital

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int _{0}^{7 x} (1+t^2)^3 dt}{\sin x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+(7x)^2)^3\cdot7}{\cos x}=7$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)=(1+t^2)^3$.  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt =f(x).$$

In this case, though, because your upper limit of integration is $u=7x$ rather than just $x$, you need to use the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^u f(t)dt = \frac{d}{du} \int_0^u f(t)dt \cdot \frac{du}{dx}=7f(u)=7(1+(7x)^2)^3.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t) $ is the integrand then the expression under limit can be written as $$7\cdot\frac{x} {\sin x} \cdot\frac{1}{u}\int_{0}^{u}f(t)\,dt$$ where $u=7x\to 0$. The first fraction tends to $1$ and the next factor tends to $f(0)$ via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Hence the desired limit is $7f(0)=7$.